# Chrome can't access video input

Tags: google-chrome, video, webrtc

I have a strange issue that the Chrome browser can not access the video input in any WebRTC apps. For example, meet.jit.si warns that it

> Failed to access your camera
>   Cannot use camera for an unknown reason

and the source selection in settings say `Permission not granted` instead of the camera dropdown (but actually I did allow to use camera and microphone).

How should I debug this issue to understand what's going on and fix it?

What have I already found:

- The problem persists on multiple Chrome versions (74 and 80)
- The problem persists on portable install of Chrome 80
- The problem persists on Chrome's sister browsers like Vivaldi
- Same WebRTC apps work fine on Chrome on other computers
- Video inputs work fine on Firefox
- Audio inputs and outputs are available without any issues
- If I enter `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}).then(console.log)` in console it prompts for camera and microphone access but never resolves the promise.
- If I enter `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(console.log)` into the console it returns list of all the devices. The device names (`label` field) are visible if I have allowed device access on that domain before and empty otherwise.

The reason is probably in the setup of the computer (the machine has multiple virtual and physical video inputs). We need to solve the issue as we need both the video inputs and WebRTC via Chrome to work simultaneously.